# Error when creating MySQL Table with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have just created a MySQL database named "test2" using PDO. Now I'm trying to create a table named "Visiteurs" but it seems my code do not work properly.

The error echoed is:

> "SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected"

(which is wrong I think) and my code is the following:

```
$serveur  = "localhost";
$login = "root";
$pass = "root";

        try{
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host = $serveur; dbname = test2", $login, $pass);

            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $codesql = "CREATE TABLE Visiteurs (
                id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                nom VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                prenom VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                email VARCHAR(70)
            )";

            $conn->exec($codesql);
            echo 'Table "Visiteurs" créée !';
        }

        catch(PDOException $e) { 
            echo 'Echec : ' . $e->getMessage(); 
        }
```

Can someone help me find where is the error?

Comment: You cannot have whitespace in the DSN string. Your `dbname` isn't being parsed.  `"mysql:host=$serveur;dbname=test2"`

Comment: Indeed, once I removed the white spaces, it worked! But then it is strange that I could successfully create a database and connect to this database with the same code (with white spaces) and without errors. Anyway, thank you so much, this tip is noted!

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you for this answer! Do I need to delete my question then or can I choose you as best answer? (don't know how to do that as you "commented" on my question...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Althout the [PDO MySQL DSN string documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) is not specific about whitespace, experience tells me that whitespace is not permitted in a DSN string.  Since you have `dbname = test2`, the `dbname` is not actually being parsed and used, so PDO complains that no database was selected. Your DSN should look like the following, with no spaces between the `key=value` pairs:

```
"mysql:host=$serveur;dbname=test2"
```

You mentioned in comments that a previous connection succeeded and you were able to issue a `CREATE DATABASE` statement. That was only due to the coincidence of the *default* host being `localhost` and your `$serveur` variable being set to `localhost` as well.  PDO probably did not parse the `host=` parameter from the DSN, but instead used `localhost` as the default connection with your user credentials. Since a `CREATE DATABASE` statement does not need to have a database selected, the `dbname=` was irrelevant.