# php - PDO with wrong host uses localhost

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, localhost, host

I have a WAMP installation with Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter Edition, Apache 2.4.23, PHP 7.0.10 (mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407), MySQL 5.7.14.

I configured a connection with:

```
$host  = 'wrong-server';
$dbase = 'db_name';
$user  = 'my_user';
$pwd   = 'my_pwd';
$connection='mysql: host='.$host.'; dbname='.$dbase;
$link = new PDO($connection , $user, $pwd);
```

where *wrong-server* doesn't exsist (it is for a test for catching errors).

When I execute the code the connection works using *localhost* as host (I know it because a query to *db_name* retrive datas).
I searched for some default behaviour or configuration without succes.

Some ideas?

Code update:

```
<?php

  $host  = '192.168.123.123'; //'localhost';
  $dbase = 'db_name';
  $user  = 'my_user';
  $pwd   = 'my_pwd';
  $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT;
  $connection='mysql: host='.$host.'; dbname='.$dbase;

  try {
    $link = new PDO($connection, $user, $pwd, $pdo_options);
    $_SESSION['DB_INFO']=array( 'db'=>$link->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME),
                                'ver'=>$link->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_VERSION),
                                'cli'=>$link->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CLIENT_VERSION ),
                                'srv'=>$link->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_INFO ),
                                );       
    print_r($_SESSION['DB_INFO']);
    }
  catch(\PDOException $err) {
    echo 'Error: '.$err->getMessage();
  };
```

Server 192.168.123.123 doesn't exsist but I have these response:

> Array ( [db] => mysql [ver] => 5.7.14 [cli] => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 241ae00989d1995ffcbbf63d579943635faf9972 $ [srv] => Uptime: 20111 Threads: 1 Questions: 354 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 125 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 118 Queries per second avg: 0.017 )

But if I set $pwd='wrong_pwd' the answer is:

> Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

**SOLUTION**

As @MichaelBerkowski states, eliminating spaces in the DSN

```
mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbase.'
```

instead of

```
mysql: host='.$host.'; dbname='.$dbase.'
```

solves the problem, so an error came out.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php#refsect1-pdo.construct-examples

Comment: You're not running a try / catch looking at your code so how would it output any error?

Comment: localhost uses a socket, try 127.0.0.1 and it will use TCP

Comment: @Farkie Now I had never realised that. You learn something every day. Thanks

Comment: MySQL is weird :D

Comment: So as the server does not exist, what did you actually put into `$host` as obfiscating a server name that does not exist seems pointless

Comment: @Option see edited code

Comment: Yes, fine. But just in case you picked a name with a special meaning, unknown to you, please show what you actually used.

Comment: @Farkie 'localhost uses a socket' sorry isn't clear for me, some reference?

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is for test pourpose

Comment: Well OBVIOUSLY `192.168.123.123` does exist and there is a MySQL database on there

Comment: Use something like `$host  = 'DoesNotExist';` and see what happens then

Comment: Remove all the spaces from the DSN string. The proper format is `'mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbase`  Whitespace is not supported.  Make it look _exactly_ like the documentation.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282289/error-when-creating-mysql-table-with-pdo/28282600#28282600

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes, these "resolved" the problem, in the way that an error came out ('_connection attempt failed_')

Comment: if you get real mysql response then it's a routing issue